# Form not adding to array and clearing

Tags: angularjs

In my controller, I have a simple array and a function:

```
$scope.newGuarantor = '';
$scope.guarantors = [
    {guarantor: 'Peter Parker'},
    {guarantor: 'Bruce Wayne'}
];

$scope.addGuarantor = function(){
    $scope.guarantors.push({
        guarantor: $scope.newGuarantor
    });
    $scope.newGuarantor = '';
};
```

In the view I have a simple list and form:

```
<tr ng-repeat="pg in guarantors">
    <td>{{pg.guarantor}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <form ng-submit="addGuarantor()">
          <input type="text" ng-model="newGuarantor"/>
          <button type="submit">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
          </button>
       </form>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

According to what I just read, I should be able to type a value into the input and click the button and the value of the input should be added to the listed array and the form cleared.

Instead, I am getting an empty row being inserted into the list and the value remains in the input.

Can anyone see what I missed?

Comment: Try creating a plunker or fiddle to demonstrate problem

Comment: I createad a JSFiddle with the code and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gbfgs0fo/3/

Comment: So confused ... the code works in the jsFiddle but on my page, I get a blank row and a full input and no errors in the console. To make sure it wasn't a stupid type, I copy-and-pasted the code from the fiddle to my attempt.

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using? Is there any other markup on your page?

Comment: 1.2.16 and most definitely other code on the page ... the full controller is 346 lines and the view is 371 lines. I just excerpted the pertinent code ... again, no errors in the console.

Comment: I am SURE it is user error but with no errors, I don't know how to find my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure WHY this worked but I changed the controller to this and it works

```
$scope.newGuarantor = {};
$scope.addGuarantor = function() {
    $scope.guarantors.push($scope.newGuarantor);
        $scope.newGuarantor = {};
    };
```

The view changed to:

```
<tr ng-repeat="pg in guarantors">
                    <td>{{pg.guarantor}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form ng-submit="addGuarantor()">
                            <input type="text" ng-model="newGuarantor.guarantor"/>
                            <button type="submit">                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

After u push the `guarantor: $scope.newGuarantor`, your resetting the `$scope.newGuarantor`. so then pushed value will be reset because of reset of `$scope.newGuarantor`.

If u need to push new object without affecting the reset of `$scope.newGuarantor`, you can use `angular.copy()` it will create a new copy of the `variable`, and that copy is not affected by original value. that means if u change the original value the copy value is not going to change. So there are No relationship between original and copy variables.

```
$scope.addGuarantor = function(){
var objVal = angular.copy($scope.newGuarantor);
$scope.guarantors.push({
    guarantor: objVal
});
$scope.newGuarantor = '';
```

};

Comment: I must have missed something else because the explanation makes perfect sense but this code produces for me the same result -- a new blank row and the input still filled.

Comment: It's not a correct answer. OP's code works fine in the first place. Moreover simple values (such as strings) are always passed by copy, never by reference in JavaScript. That's why calling "copy" on a string will not change the way this code works.